# How does application gets to know for which access point wifi broadcast is received

Tags: android

When we register for a wifi related broad cast receiver like 'SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION' in `onReceiver` call back function, how we get to know that for which wifi access points we have received this event. I don't find any Extra in the received intent whihc can give me this information.

Does any body know the way by which we can get the information related to access point when we receive wifi related broadcast receiver.

I have also tried following:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    if( action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) ) 
    {
        String ssid = "Not Found";
        WifiManager wifiManager = getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if( wifiManager != null )
        {
            WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo(); 
            ssid = info.getSSID();
        }
        Log.d("", "SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION FOR SSID:"+ssid);
    }        
}
```

Above code works only in completed state and not in disconnected state.
Is there any broadcast that can tell me wifi access point supplicant state.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this, i think Android should some information related to access point when it sends broadcast related to supplicant state.